# Not able to understand python regex with ?=

Tags: python, regex

I am not able to understand how these regex works and when they are used. I haven't found concrete examples of these regex on python website. I know sed awk but haven't used these type of regex there

```
(?=...)
(?<=...)
(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
```

Comment: They're all explained in [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) of the `re` docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(?=...)` is a [*positive lookahead assertion*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It matches if there is the part in parentheses after `?=` matches at the current position, but it will not consume any characters for the match. E.g. the regex `a(?=b)` will match an `a` followed by a `b`, but won't return the `b` as part of the match.

`(?<=...)` is the same, but a look *behind*, i.e. it looks backwards. Again, it doesn't consume anything.

`(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)` is a [*conditional*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). If the [*named group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) `id/name` matched, then the string must match `yes-pattern` at this point, otherwise `no-pattern`.

To be honest, though, those are quite advanced features and I cannot remember ever having used a conditional. Lookaround is more common, but often very constrained by the regex engines, e.g. lookbehind can only be done with fixed-length strings in many cases.

Comment: The site I linked there several times is a really great resource in learning about regular expressions.

Comment: @Joey: `lookahead can only be done with fixed-length strings` You mean look-behind? Look-ahead is equivalent to starting a new match from the current position with the regex inside look-ahead, which is easy to implement.

Comment: @Joey: The condition in Python is quite unique compared to other regex flavors, actually... Other supports regex, instead of name group inside.

Comment: nhahtdh: Yes, I meant look-behind.

Comment: nhahtdh: Other engines support either a regex or a capturing group. But as regular-expressions.info notes: »Python supports conditionals using a numbered or named capturing group. Python does not support conditionals using lookaround, even though Python does support lookaround outside conditionals. Instead of a conditional like `(?(?=regex)then|else)`, you can alternate two opposite lookarounds: `(?=regex)then|(?!regex)else)`.« – There is a workaround.